# Aggregation with limited time range from another table presto

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

I have a table that contains date, productID, amount, userid.
it looks like this

```
table 1
date       userid   amount  productID
2019-07-01  111       10    43214
2019-07-15  112       20    22551
2019-07-19  113       10    22551
2019-08-19  114       30    22551
2019-08-20  111       20    52212
2019-08-20  115       40    22225
2019-08-20  155       50    55521
2019-08-23  155       50    55521
2019-08-23  155       50    55521
```

I also have a table that will be use as a reference in aggregation.
the 2nd table is contains productID, start_date, end_date.

```
table 2
product ID  start_date  end_date
22551   2019-07-19  2019-08-20
22225   2019-07-19  2019-08-20
55521   2019-07-19  2019-08-20
```

desired result is to calculate sum(amount) from table 1 based on the rules from table 2. desired result looks like this

```
result
productID   sum(amount)
22551   40
22225   40
55521   50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select t1.productId, sum(t1.amount)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.productId = t2.productId and
        t1.date >= t2.start_date and
        t1.date <= t2.end_date
group by t1.productId;
```

Answer (score 0):

use aggregation

```
select t1.productid
     , sum(amount) 
  from table1 t1 
  join table2 t2 
    on t1.productid = t2.productid  
   and t1.date >= t2.start_date 
   and t1.date <= t2.end_date
 group 
    by t1.product
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland when i am editing with date you given down vote

Comment: @RaymondNijland sorry i am for my guessing

Comment: No problem .. annyhow iam going to remove mine comments, as your answer is changed to something which does give the correct results.